# Securing a website

Tags: php, security, web

I'm currently looking into a web site that has been hacked for phishing purposes. Apparently, a PHP file was introduced and used to upload files and perhaps change directory permissions. I suspect this was done through a public writable directory or through an unsecure image upload script.

What steps can I take to make the site as secure as possible?

Comment: Without knowing ANYTHING about your setup, we can't help you.  You need to be much more descriptive.  Why do you think there is a public-writable directory?  Where is this unsecure image upload script, and what is its source code?  What do your logs say?  And finally... do you run WordPress?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency

Comment: This is a very long topic, but, to get started, take a look at the access log. You may find there from where the malicious upload was made...

Comment: This probably belongs on webmasters. There's a long list of things you need to do on both the server and in your code. Once you have the vulnerability narrowed down to a specific source, if that source is in the programming, post the problem here.

Comment: @Brad: PHP, MySQL and the site is based on osCommerce. The permissions on a few directories were set to 777 which was odd. The actual upload script is used to add images to article descriptions. I found a few PHP files in there that weren't on localhost so I'm willing to bet that there's a flaw in the script or the directories were incorrectly set.

Comment: @NemoStein: The logs showed some weird accesses to a PHP file that may has been used as a sort of uploader. @Chris: Didn't know there was a Stack Exchange site for webmaster. Will check it out and have a look at the upload script tommorow.

Answer (score 3):

The most important step is to restore the code form a backup. The attakers could create any backdoor for future use.

Your `http_access` logs could probably tell the original point of intrusion.

Also check the file permissions your webhost uses. In many cases the vulnerability lies not inside the page itself but the hosting company not separating the space of different customers (so it could have spread from an other customer on the same webhost).

Comment: This IMO incomplete, you don't know where the vulnerability started, what is the point of restoring without changing anything?

Comment: I did not say it was the **only** step, did I? In the same sentence I write down what's the point: to eliminate any additional backdoors which may be much more hidden than the original vulnerability.

Comment: Fair enough, I still don't think it is helpful (not your fault but the questions).

Answer (score 1):

The question is tagged PHP so I'm assuming that your server side language is PHP. It is also a fairly general question but some advice is

1. If only image files are meant to be uploaded verify that the file has a valid image extension and mime type and use getimagesize(). Even if you are not accepting only image files check the extension and mime type against a whitelist of allowed extensions and types. Also when you use move_uploaded_file choose your own name and extension.
2. Ensure that arbitary files can't be requested by keeping your upload directory outside the web root and checking any data that your file requests depend on.

There is more information [here](http://hungred.com/useful-information/secure-file-upload-check-list-php/)

Answer (score 1):

The two most common attacks my php websites receive is SQL injection and Remote File Inclusion. My IDS picks up about 6 attacks per day. The #1 thing you can do as a developer is always validate user input. Never pass user input (like request variables) directly to a SQL query.

Read up on remote file inclusion:

http://www.theprohack.com/2010/07/simple-tutorial-on-remote-file.html